# RoR: route with optional parameter uses query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the route below, which is not nested, or namespaced - it's a root route.

`get 'discover(/:genre)' => 'home#discover', as: :discover, :genre => /[a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i`

Which works fine. But calling the path with the below gives an incorrect URL:

`<%= link_to g, discover_path(:genre => g.slug) %>`

Gives

`/discover?genre=house`

Which works fine, but I would like it as `/discover/house`.

Tried many combinations of `:genre => g` but none change. What am I missing?

**Update:**

Server restart and this works. Route caching huh?

Comment: did you try `discover_path(g.slug)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with it

```
<%= link_to g, discover_path(g.slug) %>
```

Thanks